# Why do the queried data result of client side and program side of Apache IoTDB are not the same?

Tags: apache-iotdb

I would like to ask why the data result queried from the Apache IoTDB client side is different from the data queried from the program? In the end of the result queried from the program, there is a [Time] at the end. What does this [Time] at the end refers to? How can I change to make the result the same?

Anyone can deal this problem？Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is a problem with the way your program prints the result set. As long as the actual data queried from Apache IoTDB and the result printed by your program are the same, you can ignore the [Time] part of the data.